# Lining up multiplication table

Tags: c#

```
private void multiBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
        for (int b = 1; b <= 10; b++)
            lblTable.Text = (a + " * " + b + " = " + (a * b));

    for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
        for (int b = 1; b <= 10; b++) 
            lblTable.Text += (a + " * " + b + " = " + (a * b));
}
```

It's doing exactly what I want it to do when it comes to multiplying. It's just not lined up in rows. It prints out the multiplication for integers 1 to 10. I just need them in rows and columns, could anyone explain to me how to do that through a label.  really don't know how to explain what it's doing but in my gui it prints out like "10*10=1001*1=11*2=21*3=3" and so on it just keeps going like that. I'm not even sure why it starts out with 10*10=100

Comment: For a graphical program, remember that for proper lining columns you should use a [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), which is not the default. The *Courier* family has this characteristic. Or even better, use a console project instead.

Comment: I've already did a console project. I'm trying to see how to do it in GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the newline character, which will put each item on a new row. For columns, it is a little trickier. Using a fixed width font and some padding around the numbers should do.

First, the newline code addition:

```
lblTable.Text += (a + " * " + b + " = " + (a * b) + "\n");
```

Or, a preferred format for many is to use string.Format for the string:

```
lblTable.Text += (string.Format("{0} * {1} = {2}\n", a, b, (a * b)));
```

To get them to align, you can use the `PadLeft` string method. In the example below, I am assuming that `a` and `b` will have less than or equal to two digits, and `a * b` will have less than or equal to 3 digits (remember this will only work if you use a fixed-width font, like Consolas):

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
{
    for (int b = 1; b <= 10; b++)
    {
        lblTable.Text += (string.Format("{0} * {1} = {2}\n",
            a.ToString().PadLeft(2),
            b.ToString().PadLeft(2),
            (a * b).ToString().PadLeft(3)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your PadNumber method is redundant, check out `String.PadLeft` and `String.PadRight`

Comment: @rshepp Nice catch! I did not know about that one. Updated sample to use built-in static string method.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear what it is exactly you want. But note that you can insert newline characters between each line (Environment.NewLine) to force a line-break, to have text displayed on successive rows (lines) in the Label.

For example:

```
lblTable.Text += a + " * " + b + " = " + (a * b) + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: I really don't know how to explain what it's doing but in my gui it prints out like "10*10=1001*1=11*2=21*3=3" and so on it just keeps going like that. I'm not even sure why it starts out with 10*10=100

Comment: It's good to be able to explain what it's doing (preferably by providing a good code example and screenshot illustrating the specific issue), but it's even better to be able to explain what you'd _rather_ it does. :) In any case, see the example I added in case it addresses your question.